# Consume from a Kafka Cluster through SSH Tunnel

Tags: apache-kafka, ssh-tunnel

We are trying to consume from a Kafka Cluster using the Java Client. The Cluster is a behind a Jump host and hence the only way to access is through a SSH Tunnel. But we are not able read because once the consumer fetches metadata it uses the original hosts to connect to brokers. Can this behaviour be overridden? Can we ask Kafka Client to not use the metadata?

Comment: You can't turn off metadata request or the client will have no way to know which broker has the current leader for each partition. This should work if the brokers are configured properly to advertise the ip or domain name of the tunnel as well as the normal internal listen ports

Comment: My solution is edit the hosts file
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703898/527277

Comment: The official way is to change the `advertised.listeners` setting. Changing the host file is a hack. Have a look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75530317/828366

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not as far as I know.

The trick I used when I needed to do something similar was:

1. setup a virtual interface for each Kafka broker
2. open a tunnel to each broker so that broker n is bound to virtual interface n
3. configure your `/etc/hosts` file so that the advertised hostname of broker n is resolved to the ip of the virtual interface n.

Es.

**Kafka brokers**:

- broker1 (advertised as broker1.mykafkacluster)
- broker2 (advertised as broker2.mykafkacluster)

**Virtual interfaces**:

- veth1 (192.168.1.1)
- veth2 (192.168.1.2)

**Tunnels**:

- broker1: `ssh -L 192.168.1.1:9092:broker1.mykafkacluster:9092 jumphost`
- broker2: `ssh -L 192.168.1.2:9092:broker1.mykafkacluster:9092 jumphost`

`/etc/hosts`:

- 192.168.1.1 broker1.mykafkacluster
- 192.168.1.2 broker2.mykafkacluster

If you configure your system like this you should be able reach all the brokers in your Kafka cluster.

**Note:** if you configured your Kafka brokers to advertise an ip address instead of a hostname the procedure can still work but you need to configure the virtual interfaces with the same ip address that the broker advertises.

Comment: I don't have liberties to do all this as the kafka clusters that I need to connect are many and the clients that I want to connect them from are also dynamic. So, cannot really change /etc/hosts manually. Also, I don't have access to them to change advertised ips.

Comment: when I create a vif (sudo ip addr add 10.x.x.x/32 dev eth0) (IP of my broker) then I can't access the broker anymore (I got could not establish connection) till I delete the VIF again. (I've brokers with only an IP so I'm creating a VIF with same IP as the broker as you told)

Comment: works like a charme, but you have to create virtual interface/tunnels for all brokers in order to work properly. also to create virtual interface in mac: sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 192.168.1.1 this will create virtual interface on loopback. repeat this for all brokers

Answer (score 13):

You don't actually have to add virtual interfaces to acces the brokers via SSH tunnel if they advertise a hostname. It's enough to add a hosts entry in `/etc/hosts` of your client and bind the tunnel to the added name.

Assuming `broker.kafkacluster` is the advertised.hostname of your broker:

`/etc/hosts`:
127.0.2.1   broker.kafkacluster

Tunnel:
`ssh -L broker.kafkacluster:9092:broker.kafkacluster:9092 <brokerhostip/name>`

Comment: What is `127.0.2.1` bound to?  Doesn't this IP address have to be bound to an network interface as well?

Comment: The local host will reply to all 127.x.x.x addresses

Comment: Does this property hold for MacOS as well? Pinging 127.x.x.(2+) results in timeouts.

Comment: For mac you need to add an alias for each loopback address as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/458875/how-do-you-get-loopback-addresses-other-than-127-0-0-1-to-work-on-os-x)

Comment: I don't known what is advertised.hostname of my broker, I only have been given ip from 3rd party developer, how can I find out advertised.hostname?

Answer (score 7):

Try [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle) like this:

```
sshuttle -r user@host broker-1-ip:port broker-2-ip:port broker-3-ip:port
```

Of course, the list of broker depends on advertised listeners broker setting.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely best solution for me was to use `kafkatunnel` (https://github.com/simple-machines/kafka-tunnel). Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `/etc/hosts` file is **NOT** the right way.

Quoting Confluent blog post:

> **I saw a Stack Overflow answer suggesting to just update my hosts file…isn’t that easier?**
>
> This is nothing more than a hack to work around a misconfiguration instead of actually fixing it.

You need to set `advertised.listeners` (or `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` if you’re using Docker images) to the external address (host/IP) so that clients can correctly connect to it. Otherwise, they’ll try to connect to the internal host address—and if that’s not reachable, then problems ensue.

[Confluent blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/)

Additionally you can have a look at [this Pull Request](https://github.com/rudderlabs/rudder-server/pull/3007) on GitHub where I wrote an integration test to connect to Kafka via SSH. It should be easy to understand even if you don't know Golang.

There you have a full client and server example (see `TestSSH`). The test is bringing up actual Docker containers and it runs assertions against them.

**TL;DR** I had to configure the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` when connecting over SSH so that the host advertised by each broker would be one reachable from the SSH host. This is because the client connects to the SSH host first and then from there it connects to a Kafka broker. So the host in the `advertised.listeners` must be reachable from the SSH server.